# Lookup using contains match

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have to design ETL to load data into a table. But, I shouldnt load values matching keys in a lookup table. Eg.

```
*Input Table*
Cab Ride
Ride in Cab
Booked Cab
Self drive
Car pooling

*Lookup Table*
Cab
Taxi


*Destination Table*
Self drive
Car pooling
```

As we can see in destination table we are not loading data that contains `Cab`

Please let me know if this possible in Pentaho or SQL

Comment: So the requirement is "load the row if it does NOT contain any string found in the lookup table", correct? This could be done with the `Regex Evaluation` step an a parent Job, but it won't be very fast. It's probably better to do it in JavaScript with the `Modified Java Script Value` step.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers that is correct, load if not contains a match in lookup table. I will try with Regex Evaluator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is building a regex

- Your lookup table feeds the various strings that you want to filter
  out (or in);
- Using a group by step you concatenate all those strings
  separated by |; the result is "Cab|Taxi".
- Prepend .*( and append
  ).* with a calculator step, ending up with .*(Cab|Taxi).*; call this field "regex_filter"
- Cross join this single row with the main data stream;
- Now you can use a filter rows with condition "NOT input_field REGEXP regex_filter". (you may want to prepend (?i) to the the regex to make it case
  insensitive).

See attached example: [Regex filter in PDI 5.4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0M8cKinNZS8bnNQQTAxTWx4XzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: thank you for the solution. I will try this. But my look table has lot may values. almost 10K records.